# How can I align two cases (two automatically indexed equations)?

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, cases

How can I align these cases? I also want to keep the equations indexed automatically. 
I saw some previous topics on this but I wonder if it can be done without changing too much the code (not rewrite it completely).

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editoria
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x_{1, 2} = 
\begin{cases}
m x_{n} & \text{if } p_{2}=1 \\
(1-m) x_{n} & \text{if } q_{2}=1 \\
0  & \text{if } (p_{2}=0) \wedge (q_{2}=0)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_{k} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{m }{1-m} x_{n}& \text{if } p_{3}\not=0 \\
\frac{(1-m)}{m}x_{n} & \text{if } q_{3}\not=0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using two `equation` environments, combine them into a single `align` environment, placing an `&` just before the `=` sign in each, and placing `\\ ` after the first `\end{cases}`.  You may want to add a bit of vertical space there too, say by specifying `\\[6pt]` (or other appropriate amount, and no space before the opening bracket).  Don't leave any blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

First, please keep in mind that `subfig` has been obsoleted for years and should no longer be used.

Back to your question, simply use the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x_{1, 2} &= 
\begin{cases}
m x_{n} & \text{if } p_{2}=1 \\
(1-m) x_{n} & \text{if } q_{2}=1 \\
0  & \text{if } (p_{2}=0) \wedge (q_{2}=0)
\end{cases}\\
x_{k} &= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{m }{1-m} x_{n}& \text{if } p_{3}\not=0 \\
\frac{(1-m)}{m}x_{n} & \text{if } q_{3}\not=0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which yields:
[image: Result]

Also, you might consider using `dcases` instead of `cases` for better readibility, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, how can I align "if"s as well?

Comment: Not as far as I know, sorry. Unless I missed a feature, I'd do that with an array, and generate the equation numbers manually.

Comment: I see. You mentioned about subfig being obsoleted. What should I use to substitute it?

Comment: To align the "if"s, you want to make the width of the left-hand side of the `cases` the same.  Pick the longest LHS, then in the other `cases`, enter one line as `\mathrlap{<expression to be printed>}\hphantom{$<long expression>$}`.  Requires `mathtools`.

Comment: @hana It's `subcaption`. A small tip: every once in a while, check CTAN. For example, [the subfig page](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) indicates that it's obsolete and points you to its replacement. In fact `subfig` has been obsoleted twice.

Comment: How would I left align x_{1,2} and x_k?